# Custom Query in JPARepository creating the right WHERE clause

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-boot

I'm pretty new to Spring Boot. I want to be able to enter the `durationWeeks` and to get all `artists` with a `production` which has the entered duration value. So I decided to try a custom query.

This is a snippet how all the data is displayed in postman:

```
{
    "idArtist": 4,
    "name": "Llewellyn Eastby",
    "email": "leastby3@google.ru",
    "production": [
        {
            "idProduction": 19,
            "durationWeeks": 23,
            "clips": {
                "idClip": 122,
                "dtype": "Clip",
                "name": "African pied wagtail"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my `artist` object. `Artist` and `production` are linked with a `@OneToMany` relationship:

```
@Entity 
public class Artist {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long idArtist;

private String name;
private String email;

@OneToMany
private List<Production> production;

{...Constructor, Getter and Setter...}
```

And this is my `production` object which has one more relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Production {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long idProduction;

private int durationWeeks;

@ManyToOne
private Clip clips;
```

At the moment this is my custom query:

```
@Query("SELECT ar FROM Artist ar, Production pr WHERE ar.idArtist = /*...*/  AND pr.durationWeeks = ?1")
public List<Artist> getArtistByDuration(int duration);
```

I tried different statements in the where clause but nothing works. What am I missing to get the `artist` by the `durationWeeks`?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Something like `SELECT ar FROM Artist ar JOIN ar.production pr WHERE pr.durationWeeks = :duration`. should do the trick. Or removing the `@Query` and use `findByProduction_DurationWeeks(int duration)` might also work.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the result? An error, an empty list ? And which of the 2 solutions did you try.

Comment: The code compiles but then when I try it on postman it just gives me a "Not Found" back. I tried the first one since I need to do a query for my school assignment.

Comment: Do you have data that matches? As the query should just work.

Comment: Yes, I'm specifically aiming for data in my workbench. I tried to look for other data but still gives me a Not_Found.

Comment: But is that data really there? Did you commit it so that it is really persisted?